# How to monitor a group of tasks in celery?

Tags: python, celery

I have a situation where a periodic monthly `big_task` reads a file and enqueue one chained-task per row in this file, where the chained tasks are `small_task_1` and `small_task_2`:

```
class BigTask(PeriodicTask):

    run_every = crontab(hour=00, minute=00, day_of_month=1)

    def run(self):
        task_list = []
        with open("the_file.csv" as f:
            for row in f:
                t = chain(
                        small_task_1.s(row),
                        small_task_2.s(),
                     )
                task_list.append(t)
            gr = group(*task_list)
            r = gr.apply_async()
```

**I would like to get statistics about the number of enqueued, failed tasks** (and detail about the exception) for each `small_task`, as soon as all of them are finished (whatever the status is) to send a summary email to the project admins.

I first thought of using `chord`, but `callback` is not executed if any of the `headers` task fails, which will surely happen in my case.

I could also use `r.get()` in the `BigTask`, very convenient, but not recommended to wait for a task result into another task (even if here, I guess the risk of worker deadlock is poor since task will be executed only once a month).

Important note: input file contains ~700k rows.

How would you recommend to proceed?

Comment: celery version?

Comment: I am currently using 3.1.25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can help you to monitor, but about the `chord` and the `callback` issue you could use [link_error](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks) callback (for catching exceptions). In your case for example you can use it like:

```
small_task_1.s(row).set(link_error=error_task))
```

and implement celery `error_task` that send you notification or whatever.

In celery 4, you can set it once for the all canvas (but it didn't work for me in 3.1):

```
r = gr.apply_async(link_error=error_task)
```

For the monitoring part, you can use [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) of course.

Hope that help

**EDIT:** An alternative (without using additional persistency) would be to catch the exception and add some logic to the result and the callback. For example:

```
def small_task_1():
    try:
       // do stuff
       return 'success', result
    except:
       return 'fail', result
```

and then in your callback task iterate over the results tuples and check for fails because doing the actual logic.

Comment: `link_error` will be called for each task, then I could simply use `CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS` but I expect several hundreds of tasks to fail, hard to analyse. flower is great, but the problem is that I would have to check it regularly to know when the tasks are done.

Comment: @stellasia I think that the latter example (in celery 4) will be called once - but I'll edit my answer with alternatives.

Comment: I like your last solution, will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @stellasia you're welcome, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution to be iterate over the group results, after the group is ready.

When you issue a Group, you have a ResultSet object. You can .save() this object, to get it later and check if .is_ready, or you can call .join() and wait for the results.

When it ends, you can access .results and you have a list of AsyncResult objects. These objects all have a .state property that you can access and check if the task was successul or not.

However, you can only check the results after the group ends. During the process, you can get the value of .completed_count() and have an idea of group progress.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.ResultSet

Answer (score 0):

The solution we use for a partly similar problem where celery builtin stuff (tasks states etc) doesn't really cut it is to manually store desired informations in Redis and retrieve them when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the porposal! I will probably end up with such a solution to get stats about the different exceptions. However, my main problem is to find a way to determine "when needed", mine being "when all tasks are done"